# Remove duplicate but keep the order

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

```
rmdup :: [Int] -> [Int]
rmdup [] = []
rmdup (x:xs) | x `elem` xs = rmdup xs
             | otherwise = x: rmdup xs
```

The code above removes duplicate from a list of Integer but it removes the first occurrence and keeps the second one. For instance:

```
rmdup [1,2,3,1,4]
```

will result:

```
[2,3,1,4]
```

How can I change it to keep the order and yield this: `[1,2,3,4]`? **Note**, I don't want to use built-in functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the following? This avoids the crazily inefficient `acc ++ [x]` and also to reverse the given list twice:

```
rmdup :: Eq a => [a] => [a]
rmdup xs = rmdup' [] xs
  where
    rmdup' acc [] = []
    rmdup' acc (x:xs)
      | x `elem` acc = rmdup' acc xs
      | otherwise    = x : rmdup' (x:acc) xs
```

Comment: This removes at most one element; you probably meant `rmdup' acc xs` for the ``x `elem` acc`` case.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for but please edit your answer with regard to @raymonad's comment.

Comment: Right! Sorry, I did only test my code on the original example ;)

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve what you want is to pass the input list in the reverse order and once when the computation is finished then reverse the result again. Although, this solution is not efficient.

```
rmdup :: [Int] -> [Int]
rmdup xs = reverse $ rmdup' (reverse xs)
  where
    rmdup' [] = []
    rmdup' (x:xs) | x `elem` xs = rmdup' xs
                  | otherwise = x: rmdup' xs
```

Demo:

```
ghci> rmdup [1,2,3,1,4]
[1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to ignore those later occurrences of an element if you saw it before, then you need to record what you have seen, looks like `foldl` or `foldl'` is what you are looking for.

Here is a possible implementation:

```
import Data.List (foldl')

rmdup :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
rmdup = foldl' step []
    where step acc x
            | x `elem` acc = acc
            | otherwise = acc++[x]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `elem` is O(n), the solutions based on using it to check each element are O(n^2).
The "standard" efficient solution to the duplicates problem is to sort the list before checking for duplicates. Here, since we need to preserve elements, we have to be a bit more careful.

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

rmdupSorted :: Eq b => [(a,b)] -> [(a,b)]
rmdupSorted (x@(_,xb):xs@((_,yb):_)) | xb == yb  = rmdupSorted xs
                                     | otherwise = x : rmdupSorted xs
rmdupSorted xs = xs      -- 0 or 1 elements

rmdup :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
rmdup = map snd . sort . rmdupSorted . sortBy (comparing snd) . zip [0..]

main = print $ rmdup [1,2,3,4,5,4,6,1,7]
```

Assuming that the `sortBy` function is a *stable sort*, the `rmdup` function will remove all the duplicate occurrences of any element but for the one occurring last. If `sortBy` is not stable, then `rmdup` will remove all the occurrences but for an unspecified one (i.e., `rmdup [1,2,1]` could return `[1,2]` instead of `[2,1]`.).

Complexity is now O(n log n).

We now need to rewrite the above without library functions, as the OP requested. I will leave this as an exercise to the reader. :-P